# Create anonymous type from string

Tags: c#

So I have a anonymous type which I have used ToString on, and put into a file. It looks like this (and remarkably like JSon...):

```
{ Name = Name, Description = Description, Status = Pending, Key = Template, SubmittedBy = MyName, Identity = 2fb7a40b-e07a-4f1a-a48b-2c2720567f35 }
```

now I want to go the other way (edit:take the string from a file and put it into a format I can put into a known object) and put it into an anonymous type (which has the same properties, but I don't care if they are castable or anything like that, I just want a quick way to do something like.

```
AnonObject = GetObjectFromFile(blah);
RealObject.Name = AnonObject.Name;
```

I only have an interface for RealObject, so I can't add serialisation to the class. If you know a better way, let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Is `Identity` a guid? Looks like it.

Comment: You may be able to use a JSON parser such as JSON.net.

Comment: Identity is a guid. I don't want to add a library if I can help it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous types are defined at *compile* time, and included in the assembly just like any other type. Creating them at execution time would require dynamically creating types - it's likely to end up getting messy really quickly.

If you're using .NET 4, you could use an `ExpandoObject` and `dynamic`; otherwise I'd probably just use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and change this:

```
RealObject.Name = AnonObject.Name;
```

to

```
RealObject["Name"] = AnonObject.Name;
```

(Or vice versa. It's not really clear what you're doing.)

Comment: Does ExpandoObject serialise?

Comment: Okay, it doesn't. I'll just manually parse the string into RealObject rather than using an intermediary. Thanks.